# Inserting Content Values in multiple tables in Sqlite Android Application

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am brand new to multiple tables in an `SQLite` database and am trying to find out what the best practices are for inserting values into multiple tables. My main question is do I need to Create another `ContentValues` object for inserting the values into a second table? I am really stumped on how to perform the `insert()`. Here is what I am trying so far.

Here are the two tables and schema

```
/* Creating a common attributes table here. */
    private static final String CREATE_COMMON_ATTRIBUTES_TABLE = "create table "
            + COMMON_ATTRIBUTES_TABLE + "(" + DBColCons.UID_COMMON_ATTRIBUTES + " integer" +
            " primary key autoincrement, " + DBColCons.GPS_POINT+ " integer not null, "
            + DBColCons.EXISTING_GRADE_GPS_POINT+ " integer not null, "
            + DBColCons.COVER+ " real not null, "+ DBColCons.NOTES+ " text, "
            + DBColCons.DATE+ " text)";

    /* Creating a weld table here */
    private static final String CREATE_WELD_TABLE = " create table " +WELD_TABLE+ "("
            + DBColCons.UID_WELD + " integer primary key, " + DBColCons.WELD_TYPE +
            " text, " + DBColCons.WELD_ID + " text, " + DBColCons.DOWNSTREAM_JOINT +
            " text, " + DBColCons.UPSTREAM_JOINT + " text, " + DBColCons.HEAT_AHEAD +
            " text, " + DBColCons.LENGTH_AHEAD + " real, " + DBColCons.WALL_CHANGE +
            " text, " + DBColCons.WELD_WALL_THICKNESS + " text, "
            + DBColCons.WELDER_INITIALS + " text, foreign key("+DBColCons.WELD_ID+") references" +
            "("+DBColCons.GPS_POINT+"))";
```

Here is the method I am wanting to use for the `insert()` with some class `getters()` for the Weld class, which I am passing in as a parameter.

```
public boolean insertWeld(Weld weld) {
        /* Get a writable copy of the database */
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        /* Content values to insert with Weld class setters */
        ContentValues contentValuesWeld = new ContentValues();
        try {
            contentValuesWeld.put(DBColCons.GPS_POINT, weld.getGpsPoint());
            contentValuesWeld.put(DBColCons.WELD_TYPE, weld.getWeldType());
            contentValuesWeld.put(DBColCons.WELD_ID, weld.getWeldId());
            contentValuesWeld.put(DBColCons.DOWNSTREAM_JOINT, weld.getDownstreamJoint());
            contentValuesWeld.put(DBColCons.UPSTREAM_JOINT, weld.getUpstreamJoint());
            contentValuesWeld.put(DBColCons.HEAT_AHEAD, weld.getHeatAhead());
            contentValuesWeld.put(DBColCons.LENGTH_AHEAD, weld.getLengthAhead());
            contentValuesWeld.put(DBColCons.EXISTING_GRADE_GPS_POINT, weld.getExistingGradePoint());
            contentValuesWeld.put(DBColCons.COVER, weld.getCover());
            contentValuesWeld.put(DBColCons.WALL_CHANGE, weld.getWallChange());
            contentValuesWeld.put(DBColCons.WELD_WALL_THICKNESS, weld.getWeldWallThickness());
            contentValuesWeld.put(DBColCons.WELDER_INITIALS, weld.getWelderInitials());
            contentValuesWeld.put(DBColCons.NOTES, weld.getNotes());
            /* adding the date in here to the row. */
            contentValuesWeld.put(DBColCons.DATE, String.valueOf(mStrDate));
            /* Inserting into the weld table */
            db.insertWithOnConflict(WELD_TABLE, DBColCons.WELDER_INITIALS, contentValuesWeld,
                    SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_NONE);
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The values for `DBColCons.GPS_POINT`,`DBColCons.EXISTING_GRADE_GPS_POINT`,`DBColCons.GPS_COVER` and `DBColCons.NOTES` are what I want to insert into the Common_Attributes_Table. This is where I am really confused. Do I need to create a separate `ContentValues` object for those specific values and insert them into the desired table with a separate db.insert() method along with the one I am already using with the insert on the WELD_TABLE?

Help I am lost in this train wreck. Ha.
Thank you all.

Comment: Would you mind giving what was the error displayed?

Comment: Do you plan on inserting the exact same record into multiple tables?  If so, you might want to rethink your database design.

Comment: @falsify. I have not run anything yet so no error. I am wanting to get it correct before carrying on with more. Sorry I should have been more specific.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen. I don't think so initially. I will be making more tables however and the Common_Attributes_Table will be a part of all the other tables as well, since those specific values are shared by all the different types of data I plan on collecting. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `insert()` (or `insertWithConflict()`) for each table you are inserting values into. Unless the values are the same, this implies you will need another `ContentValue`s per table.

If you intend for these inserts to be committed as a single atomic operation, consider using a transaction.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = ...;
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    // do your inserts/etc. here
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try doing this as you have suggested. Thanks.